# How can I make table of variation by Mathematica like tkz-tab in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, table

I use [tkz-tab](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-tab) to make this table of table of variation of the function $y =  x^3 +  3 x^2 - 9 x$.
[image]

With *Mathematica* I tried

```
f[x_] = x^3 +  3 x^2 - 9 x
Solve[f'[x] == 0, x]
f[1]
f[-3]
```

I don't know draw the table. How can I do this?

Another table of the function $f(x) = (x^2 + 4 x + 3)/(x - 1)$.

[image]

Comment: Honestly you're asking for someone to do quite a bit of work for you to reproduce niche functionality that 1) already exists elsewhere and 2) you have access to. Perhaps you could try to import the $\TeX$ output instead? I'm not sure that I see the advantage in reproducing it in Mathematica otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the goal is to generate variation table inside the notebook, then you can do the following. I took an example using `tkz-tab` from the internet and just used the code as is inside Mathematica, thanks to `MaTeX` package.

```
<< MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{amssymb,tkz-tab}"}]
MaTeX["\\begin{tikzpicture}
\\tkzTabInit[lgt=1.20, espcl=2.5]{$t$ /1,$x'(t)$ /2,$x(t)$ /2,$y'(t)$ 
/2,$y(t)$ /2} {$-\\infty$, $1$,$\\sqrt{3}$,$+\\infty$}
\\tkzTabLine{0,+,d, +, ,  +,}
\\tkzTabVar{-/$1$, +D-/$+\\infty$/$-\\infty$/, R/, +/$+\\infty$}
\\tkzTabIma{2}{4}{3}{$\\frac{1}{2}$}
\\tkzTabLine{0,+,d, +, z ,  -,}
\\tkzTabVar{-/$0$, +D-/$+\\infty$/$-\\infty$/, 
+/$\\frac{3\\sqrt{3}}{2}$, -/$-\\infty$}
\\end{tikzpicture}"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: I never used `tkz-tab` but it actually does not do any computation. You have to enter the actual data yourself. It just does formatting of the input.

I suspect you are looking for a function that does the actual computation (i.e. find the min/max, asymptotes, slope (+ or -) and inflection points) and then also draw the table.

I do not think such a function exist in Mathematica. You can search the Wolfram Functions repository or Wolfram demo site. I never saw one myself.

Btw, based on this [answer at mapleprimes](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/237512--Integrate-This-LaTeX-Code-Into-Maple), it looks like also Maple does not have such a function builtin. The difference is that in Mathematica one can actually call Latex via `MaTeX` package, but in Maple it is not possible do this. There is no such functionality in Maple. In Mathematica you can answer the above Maple question as follows

```
<<MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX,"Preamble"->{"\\usepackage{amssymb,tkz-tab}"}]
MaTeX["\\begin{tikzpicture} \\tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , $f(x)$ / 2}{$-\\infty$, $-5$, $-3$, 0, $+\\infty$} \\tkzTabVar{-/ $-\\infty$, +CD-/ $0$/ $2$, +D+/ $0$ /$0$, -V-/ $-2$ / $3$, +/ $+\\infty$} \\end{tikzpicture}"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I voted for you. But, I can not compile your code, because, I can not install Matex.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 if you followed instructions at https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaTeXInstall/ and can't install Matex package, then you could post separate question on this explaining what error you got and someone can help.